# Elm : Pass value to outgoing port from the update function

Tags: elm, ffi, elm-port

I have an update function that adds an `Answer` to a `Question`

Once the question has been updated with an answer, I'd like to send it to an outgoing port, while also updating my model.

```
port emitQuestion : Question -> Cmd msg

update msg model =
  AnswerQuestion answer ->
    case model.question of
      Nothing ->
        ( model, Cmd.none)

      Just question ->
        let 
          updatedQuestion = 
            { question | answer = Just answer }
        in
          ( { model | question = updatedQuestion } , Cmd.none)
```

How could I pass `updatedQuestion` to `emitQuestion` in this scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the outgoing port signature, but without a body, like this:

```elm
port questionUpdated : Question -> Cmd msg
```

(assuming that you have an `Question` type or alias; your question didn't specify)

Then, in the calling javascript, you define your port handler after calling Elm `init`:

```js
var app = Elm.Main.init({ node: document.querySelector('main') })
app.ports.questionUpdated.subscribe(function(data) {
  // your javascript for handling updated question
});
```

To pass that new question value to the port on update, just pass it in the second value of the return type from `update`:

```
( { model | question = updatedQuestion } , questionUpdated updatedQuestion )
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.
Unfortunately I asked my question poorly.

I'm wondering that once I have checked I have a question and have updated it with 
the answer `updatedQuestion = { question | answer = Just answer }` - how can I then send this to the emitQuestion port, while also saving it to the model?